# how to load Huge amount of data into kendogrid in a fraction of seconds

Tags: kendo-grid

I have kendo grid and clear filter button in my application,I have huge amount of data in my application,When we clear the filtering data it takes too much of time.Is it possible to clear the filter with in fraction of seconds.here is my grid code

```
           var result=  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                autoBind: false,
              dataSource: db,
                         pageable: true,
  filterable:true,
  columns:[

      {field:"OrderID",title:"OrderID",filterable:true},
           {field:"Freight",title:"Freight"} ,
           {field:"OrderDate",title:"OrderDate" ,format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"},
   {field:"ShipCity",title:"ShipCity"} ]  

         }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mga6f/118/

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code for your problem :

```
            $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter([]);
```